# Oculus rift, quaternion and euler, how to increase range

Tags: math, oculus, euler-angles

I have access to rotation degrees from oculus. Quanterion to Euler, Euler to degrees. 
Range of pitch, roll and yaw is from -90 to 90. Is there any way to increase range -180 to 180? I know that can't use arcus functions, because it has ranges from -pi/2 to pi/2

Comment: Multiply it by 2... You cannot rotate your head more than 90 degrees.

Comment: In theory the equations should be able to work with angles in any range. We would need more details and a  code sample to see the process you are using.

Comment: Ok, i'll answer under it

Answer (score 0):

```
    double a = ts.HeadPose.ThePose.Orientation.x;
    double b = ts.HeadPose.ThePose.Orientation.y;
    double c = ts.HeadPose.ThePose.Orientation.z;
    double d = ts.HeadPose.ThePose.Orientation.w;








    double kat_x = atan2(2 * (a*b + c*d), 1 - 2 * (b*b + c*c));
    kat_x = (kat_x * 180) / 3.1415;

    double kat_y = asin(2 * (a*c - d*b));
    kat_y = (kat_y * 180) / 3.1415;

    double kat_z = atan2(2 * (a*d + b*c), 1 - 2 * (c*c + d*d));
    kat_z = (kat_z * 180) / 3.1415;
```

Ok now it's working. Instead of using atan i needed to use atan2